# how to handle response from cas authentication sucess to controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, cas

While implementing the security on Spring using CAS. After authentication from CAS how to set the response page of Spring in security.xml, after creating the ticket from cas my controller is not able to handle the request.

```
      //  security.xml configuration is ==>
      // This section is used to configure CAS. The service is the actual redirect 
      //    that will be triggered after the CAS login sequence. -->
                <bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
                    <property name="service" value="http://localhost:8086/cluster/request/abcd/"></property>
                    <property name="sendRenew" value="false"></property>
                </bean>

        // and my controller handling the request from abcd 
        @RequestMapping(value = "/abcd", method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public String dashboard(Model model) {
        }

    web.xml is 

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
      <display-name>socialcluster</display-name>


        <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml</param-value>
      </context-param>

      <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
      </filter>
     <!--  -->
      <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/social/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>


      <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
      </listener>


<servlet>
            <servlet-name>springsocial</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>springsocial</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/social/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

      <session-config>
        <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
      </session-config>
     </web-app>
```

//  and my security.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    //Enable security, let the casAuthenticationEntryPoint handle all intercepted 
    //  urls. The CAS_FILTER needs to be in the right position within the filter 
    //  chain. -->

    <security:global-method-security
        secured-annotations="enabled">
    </security:global-method-security>

    <security:http entry-point-ref="casAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"></security:intercept-url>
        <security:custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER"
            ref="casAuthenticationFilter"></security:custom-filter>

    </security:http>

    // Required for the casProcessingFilter, so define it explicitly set and 
    //specify an Id Even though the authenticationManager is created by default 
    //when namespace based config is used. -->
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider
            ref="casAuthenticationProvider"></security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <!-- This section is used to configure CAS. The service is the actual redirect 
        that will be triggered after the CAS login sequence. -->
    <bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
        <property name="service" value="http://localhost:8080/socialcluster/social/dashboard/"></property>
        <property name="sendRenew" value="false"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler"  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="http://localhost:8080/home.do" />
    </bean>

<!--    //value="http://localhost:8080/spring-security-cas/j_spring_cas_security_check"></property> -->
    <!-- The CAS filter handles the redirect from the CAS server and starts 
        the ticket validation. -->


    <bean id="casAuthenticationFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"></property>
    </bean>

    //The entryPoint intercepts all the CAS authentication requests. It redirects 
    //  to the CAS loginUrl for the CAS login page. -->
    <bean id="casAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="loginUrl"
            value="https://login.example.com/cas/login"></property>
        <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Handles the CAS ticket processing. -->
    <bean id="casAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService"></property>
        <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties"></property>
        <property name="ticketValidator">
            <bean class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator">
                <constructor-arg index="0"
                    value="https://login.example.com/cas"></constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="key" value="cas"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="casSingleSignOutFilter" class="org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter"/>

    // Invoked when the user clicks logout -->

     // logout session menamagement uncomments -->

    <bean id="logoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter">
        //logout  URL redirected to after logout success 
        <constructor-arg value="https://localhost:5543/cas/logout"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.ui.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler">
                    <property name="invalidateHttpSession" value="false"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
     -->

    // The users available for this application. -->
    <security:user-service id="userService">
        <security:user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER"></security:user>
    </security:user-service>
```

edited::::My controller is not able to identify the request

error is  **This webpage has a redirect loop**

1.) what to change so that my controller able to identify the request.

Answer (score 0):

I allway map spring security filter to `/*`. It is not absolutely necessary, but not doing so may lead to weird errors if you do not modify all default URLs.

You should use

```
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

in your web.xml, and use `<intercept-url>` in security.xml to declare the public parts of your application.

EDIT :

The service URL should be dedicated to CAS and must be publicly available.

You could change some beans in security.xml :

```
<security:http entry-point-ref="casAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/cas/**" access="PERMIT_ALL"/>        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"></security:intercept-url>
    <security:custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER"
        ref="casAuthenticationFilter"></security:custom-filter>

</security:http>

<bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
    <property name="service" value="http://localhost:8080/cas/service"></property>
    <property name="sendRenew" value="false"></property>
</bean>
```

EDIT2 :

Not noticed first, but your cas server has a login url of `https://login.example.com/cas/login` and you cas service is `http://localhost:8080/cas/service`.

CAS workflow is as following (very simplified - look at [jasig](http://www.jasig.org) or [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAS) for details) :

- client sends a request to app server
- app server sees the client has no credentials and redirects to cas server login page with a *token* and his service URL.
- cas server authenticates the client and :

  - posts to app server service URL informations to allow it to identify user
  - redirects client to app server

So the service URL must be accessible from CAS server. It can contain localhost only if cas server and app server are on same machine.

Comment: I did but after authenticating. controller is able to identifi the request parameter??
url is =>> http://localhost:8080/socialcluster/social/dashboard?ticket=ST-3687-6bTR9HWedSoT5b5iQ

Comment: ,when i updated security code i got this exception  Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurity Interceptor#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [PERMIT_ALL]

Comment: error after authenticating the page.>>This webpage has a redirect loop

Comment: @user3534375 : I made a typo. I wrote `PERMIT_ALL`, but correct spelling is `permitAll`

Comment: I've just seen that I leaved `/social/*` for filter mapping when it must be `/*` to be able to accept the authentication from CAS.

Comment: I did not notice it first : your cas server has a login url of `https://login.example.com/cas/login` if it is not on same host, you cannot use `localhost` in service url ...

Comment: @ should i give the ip-address of my system in callback url.
redirects client to app server is running my application. in case my application running on mysystem.

Comment: but my controller is not able to accept the request.

Comment: Which controller ? The post to service request should be handled by spring security filters ...

Comment: after authentication some controller will handle the authenticated response or not?? if yes how?

Comment: every time called a redirect url from
<beans:bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
     
      <beans:property name="service" value="http://localhost:8080/company/casAuthenticate.html"/>
       <beans:property name="sendRenew" value="false"/>
     </beans:bean>
any idea how to handle request after ticket validating....getting to much confusion for redirect after ticket validation in CAS